# Sort String in Flutter in Alphabetic Order

Tags: string, flutter, sorting, dart, alphabetical

I am trying to sort the below string in  alphabetic order in flutter but not able to find any such example for the same.

Please guide me how can I do the same.

```
String text = "Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
```

Comment: Do you mean each word, separated by space, in the string?

Answer (score 2):

Input: `"Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams"`

Output: `"deiinTv Mmoos Mmoos eiQtu 001 agmrs"`

Code:

```
String text = "Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
List<String> split = text.split(" ");

 
var NewData = split.map((e){
  List<String> splited = e.split('');
  splited.sort((a, b) => a.toUpperCase().compareTo(b.toUpperCase()));
  return splited.join('');
 }
);
  
  print(NewData.join(' ').toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split and sort support to do this reversing

```
List<String> splitString = text.split(' ').toList();
splitString.sort((a, b)=> a.compareTo(b)); ---> perform ascending or descending here

String data = '';
splitString.forEach((element) {
  data += ' $element';
});

print(data);
```

Output:

```
I/flutter ( 5364):  100 Momos Momos Quite Tividen grams
```

Comment: `splitString.sort((a, b)=> a.compareTo(b));` this is not clever, `splitString.sort();` is enough

Comment: also instead of pointless `forEach` need to use `splitString.join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the string into a list and sort it, like this!

```
  String text = "Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
  List<String> textList = text.split(' ');
  textList.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
  String TextSorted = textList.join(' ');
  
  print(TextSorted);
```

Output:

```
100 grams Momos Momos Quite Tividen
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Sort Strings in alphabetic order like that.

```
String text = "Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
List<String> split = text.split("");
split.sort();
print(split.toString());
```

for more information read [Sort API in Dart Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

For each word @Balasubramani Sundaram has given answer,

And for each alphabet in string you can do something like this:

```
void main() {
var s="Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
print(s);
var sRunes = s.runes;
List<int> listdata = sRunes.toList();
listdata.sort();
var sortedString="";
listdata.forEach((int rune) { 
    var chr=new String.fromCharCode(rune); 
    sortedString = sortedString + chr;
  }); 
print(sortedString);
}
```

Output:

```
Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams
     001MMQTadeegiiimmmnoooorssstuv
```

Comment: @Dude Thanks, i'll keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner defined as an extension on Strings:

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

void main() {
  String text = "Tividen Momos Momos Quite 100 grams";
  print(text.sortWords());
}

extension StringX on String {
  String sortWords({bool caseInsensitive = true}) {
    return (this.split(' ')
          ..sort(caseInsensitive ? compareAsciiUpperCase : null))
        .join(' ');
  }
}
```

You can decide to use the method case sensitive or not.